# Minions Jumping around when walking towards enemy turret

Tags: league-of-legends

When I am walking with the minions towards an enemy turret, they seem to 'jump' ahead and start attacking the turret when they were at first beside/behind me.

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Comment: sounds like a lag or a syncing problem. this question can only be answered by developers. this is probably a temporary problem

Comment: Its happened to me over the 3 years I have played the game, not even on the same computer/ modem/ location. Just trying to find someone that can give me a definitive answer if they can find one from somewhere.

Comment: there will be no answer for this question, because there is no real question. `why do the seem....` it is **probably** a lag

Comment: So if I could get a video of the minions jumping ahead would that help for an answer or should I just submit a ticket and wait two weeks for an answer

Comment: what kind-of answer do you want? "yes", "no", "they jump because their minions", "it's lag".... how do these answers help you? I really don't get your question.

Comment: Id like to know the cause and/or causes of the minions jumping. Did I not ask that clearly?

Comment: well yes, you asked that clearly. but how does it help you when you know the cause? and as i said: nobody here will be able to answer this

Comment: What if its something that can be fixed by changing 'x' setting and I do not have be confused anymore by minions disappearing then re appearing moments later?

Comment: then you should ask for a fix, not for the cause. there will still be nobody that can answer this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just lag spikes.  There is no real fix for it besides having a steady connection.